# Finding integer quantities of items with different weights such that all items can be consumed fully

Tags: linear-algebra

This is probably not the place for this, but my math skills are rusty and maybe someone will have fun with this. Practical purpose of the question is that I'm trying to put together a recipe and optimize ingredient purchases.

I have a few items of different weights and want to consume them all completely, but would need different quantities of each item to do so over a certain number of batches. The weights are all oddball numbers so a formula would be awesome.

Very basic example:

Flour comes in 1kg, say I need 500g for the recipe

Sugar comes in 0.5kg, say I need 100g for the recipe

Salt comes in 50g, say I need 10g for the recipe.

How many integer divisible batches do I need to make and how many of each item do I need to buy to make sure I have no ingredients left.

As I write this, I feel like I need to put together a system of equations, but I haven't done that since high school and those questions usually came with the system set up and I have no idea how to create one...

Comment: For each pack of flour you can make $2$ batches, for each pack of sugar you can make $5$ batches, and for each pack of salt you can make $5$ batches. The lowest common multiple is $10$, so $5$ lots of flour and $2$ lots of sugar and salt for $10$ batches overall

Comment: The same idea generalises, but if you needed for example $100$g for a recipe and a pack is $250$g then that means each pack can make $2.5$ recipes, so to make the batches integer divisible you double it to $5$ batches ($2$ packs), and then apply the lowest common multiple as before

Comment: Christ... was that it? It makes so much more sense when you put it like that.... Write it up in an answer and I can accept it if you like

Comment: Its alright! Glad I could help :)

Comment: There is a version of this problem that's fundamental in chemistry: given a chemical reaction, with a bunch of reactant and product molecules, what are the proportions of each reactant needed, and what are the proportions of each product produced? This is called "balancing" the chemical equation.